# How to manually test front-end and switch between server responses,

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am searching for a tool that help to create a UI for choosing between server mockups tests response.

(or other solution that will help while creating a front-end)

I will explain:
I am developing a front-end for webapp.
I want to manual test the app (**using my mouse and keyboard without test runner**) and without backend server.
I want to see the app in many sceniaros., when user sign-in, sign-out....

So I want to be able to **easily switch between server mock response**.

[image: mockup of who i think it needs to be]

Comment: Before you vote to close the extension, is it in-topic to ask for a tool commonly used by programers - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any answer, so I have developed it!

**You can see it here:**

http://aminag.github.io/javascript-xhr-mock-chooser/tests.host.html

**Settings File:**

http://aminag.github.io/javascript-xhr-mock-chooser/xhr-mock-settings.json

**Github**

https://github.com/AminaG/javascript-xhr-mock-chooser/

Example of Settings file:

```
{
"default_show":"true",
"data":
[
{
    "method":"get",
    "url":"/",
    "response":"GREAT"
},
{
    "name":"test 2",
    "method":"post",
    "url":"/a",
    "response":[
        {
            "response":"ok"
        },
        {
            "name":"Signed Off",
            "response":"false"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name":"test 4 /c",
    "url":"/c",
    "response":{
        "status":404
    }
},
{
    "name":"test /b ",
    "url":"/b",
    "response":{
        "content-type":"abc",
        "body":"ok"
    }
},
{
    "name":"test response multi object /d",
    "url":"/d",
    "response":[
        {
            "name":"Sigen in",
            "response":{
                    "content-type":"abc",
                    "body":"ok"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Signed Off",
            "response":"false"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "url":"/api/getJson",
    "response":"{\"json_working\":\"yes\"}"
}
]
}
```

[image]